# What Shaders are animated?

Tags: destiny-2

I'm looking for a list of shaders that are animated, or having "moving" textures, like Gambit Emerald, Rasmussen Clan (the only two I own that seem to be animated).  There's no specific category listing in the Collections Page separating animated from non-animated ones.

Comment: Night's Chill, Satou Tribe and New Age Black Armoury are animated ones I know of not in your list. Browse a list of shaders here, https://data.destinysets.com/ filter by ItemCategory 'Shader'. Might need a collaborative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## List:

### From mementos (crafted weapons only):

- Gleaming Keepsake - flawless trials card
- Triumphant Keepsake - vanguard GM nightfalls
- Scaly Keepsake - gambit
- Rime Keepsake - The Dawning
- Twighlight Keepsake - Festival of the Lost
- All Stars Memento (shader name unknown?) - Guardian Games

### Questionable Visibility

- Photo Finish* (The physical textures don't change, the glow changes colors)
- Tidesmoke* (This is almost imperceptible other than on specific sparrows)

### Eververse

- Ablaze - Eververse season 23
  +Luminous Void - Eververse

### Obtainable

- Blueshift Dreams
- dawning elegance
- goldjay
- Amethyst Bloom
- Gambit Emerald
- First Frost
- Seven Sisters
- Amethyst Bloom
- Mystoposphor
- Copperbrandm
- Laguna Cruiser

### Possibly Unobtainable

- New Age Black Armory
- Bergusian Night
- House of Meyrin
- Satou Tribe
- Rasmussen Clan

I will add any more that I find when I can.

Comment: New age black armory shader can be obtained by dismantling black armory stuff that Ada-1 sometimes has in stock. (Last week she had)